# Flyway with Spring: Can I have SQL and Java based migrations?

Tags: spring, flyway

Is it possible to have both SQL and Java based migrations? (ie: an .sql file and .java file)? If so, do they rest in the same directory?

Comment: Care to follow up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you mean with spring-boot? Please clarify what context Spring has in this question and I'll update my answer.

Aside from Spring, SQL and Java migrations are both available to you in combination. You can configure the location of your migration files, see the `locations` section of [`migrate`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/migrate) but by default your SQL and Java migration files will be found in `db/migration` on the classpath. So in a typical project that would be

```
src/main
└── java
    └── db
        └── migration
            ├── V3__M3.java
            └── V4__M4.java

└── resources
    └── db
        └── migration
            ├── V1__m1.sql
            └── V2__m2.sql
```